# How to know the history about rplidar wiki

Tags: ros, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to get the edit history about [rplidar](http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299108/how-to-know-the-history-about-rplidar-wiki/) by [kint](https://answers.ros.org/users/23070/kint/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoinMoin displays editing history of pages on the *Revision History* page, which you can access for `wiki/rplidar` here: [wiki/action/info/rplidar?action=info](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/rplidar?action=info).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0